# Implicit with more specific type not getting picked up

Tags: scala

I am building a small library adding a type class for Serialize and Deserialize.  I created a implicit that wraps the result around a scalaz Validation but delegates the rest to another implicit (code below).  My question is, in Serialize, there is the validateSer that takes a Serialize[A, B] and returns Serialize[A, Validation[Throwable, B]].  This works fine, but when I do the same for Deserialize, the compiler can't figure out which implicit to use.  How can I get this to work with both serialize and deserialize?

Serialize

```
trait Serialize[A, B] {
  def serialize(a: A): B
}

object Serialize {

  import scalaz.@@
  import Format._

  implicit def validateSer[A, B](implicit ser: Serialize[A, B]): Serialize[A, Validation[Throwable, B]] =
    new Serialize[A, Validation[Throwable, B]] {
      override def serialize(t: A): Validation[Throwable, B] =
        Validation.fromTryCatch(ser.serialize(t))
    }

  implicit def jsonSerString[A]: Serialize[A, String @@ JSON] = new Serialize[A, String @@ JSON] {
    override def serialize(t: A): String @@ JSON =
      JSON(mapper.writeValueAsString(t))
}

object HardTypeForJackson
HardTypeForJackson.serialize[Validation[Throwable, String @@ JSON]] // works
```

Deserialize

```
trait Deserialize[A, B] {
  def deserialize(a: A): B
}

object Deserialize {
  import scalaz.@@
  import Format._

  implicit def validateDes[A, B](implicit des: Deserialize[A, B]): Deserialize[A, Validation[Throwable, B]] =
    new Deserialize[A, Validation[Throwable, B]] {
      override def deserialize(a: A): Validation[Throwable, B] =
        Validation.fromTryCatch(des.deserialize(a))
    }

  implicit def jsonDesString[B: Manifest]: Deserialize[String @@ JSON, B] = new Deserialize[String @@ JSON, B] {
    override def deserialize(a: String @@ JSON): B =
      mapper.readValue[B](a)
}

JSON("foo").deserialize[Validation[Throwable, PuppetCommand]] // compiler error

    Error:(82, 41) ambiguous implicit values:
 both method validateDes in trait DeserializeInstances of type [A, B](implicit des: com.gopivotal.heimdall.util.Deserialize[A,B])com.gopivotal.heimdall.util.Deserialize[A,scalaz.Validation[Throwable,B]]
 and method jsonDesString in trait DeserializeInstances of type [B](implicit evidence$1: Manifest[B])com.gopivotal.heimdall.util.Deserialize[scalaz.@@[String,com.gopivotal.heimdall.util.Format.JSON],B]
 match expected type com.gopivotal.heimdall.util.Deserialize[scalaz.@@[String,com.gopivotal.heimdall.util.Format.JSON],scalaz.Validation[Throwable,com.gopivotal.heimdall.orchestration.PuppetCommand]]
    val parsed = JSON("foo").deserialize[Validation[Throwable, PuppetCommand]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the code I put above isn't what I was using.  I had the all implicits in a trait called DeserializeInstances and the Deserialize object just extended it.  When I move the validation implicit into the object rather than the trait, then it got picked up as expected.